# Computer suddenly turns black and won't boot again until some time

Tags: boot, hardware-failure

I'm having a strange problem with my computer. Some time after boot, the screen goes black and I have to reboot it. Fans continue spinning but hard drive stops. If I reboot it **immediately** after it does this, it won't boot, it will display the same black screen.

After waiting a while, I boot it and works fine until this happens again.

I tried cleaning it on the inside. This happens while running both Windows and Ubuntu, so it's not a software problem.

Comment: How frequently does this occur? How long is the computer running? Does it happen in different environments? When it won't boot, do you get an error or does nothing happen? Does it turn on?

Comment: This sounds like an overheating issue. Check for dust in the CPU fan and also try cleaning in the PSU without opening the box. Also, ensure that the CPU fan is working correctly.

Comment: @Raystafarian It happens after the computer has been running 10 minutes or so, sometimes even more. When it doesn't boot nothing happens. It turns on but nothing appears on the screen.

Comment: @LPChip tried cleaning, but it doesn't seem to have helped much..

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could be going on is that the fan on the CPU heat sink has failed. I've had this happen multiple times and not noticed it because the case fans make a much more obvious sound. When the fan fails the CPU chip can heat up fairly quickly, especially for high performance CPUs that may consume 40, 50 or more watts of power. The CPU eventually gets to a critical temperature and asserts a THERM_TRIP which causes the motherboard chipset to shutdown the system. When replacing the fan/heatsink make sure to clean out the old thermal compound off the top of the CPU and replace with new fresh material. Note that many of the new fan/heatsink assemblies may already have thermal compound on the heatsink surface that sits on top the CPU.

You should definitely consider that the problem may be the monitor as opposed to the computer. It is a very common symptom for monitors whose power supply capacitors are going bad to work for a time from cold start and then flick off.

In my own experience the problem gets worse and worse until it comes to the point that the monitor will turn on for a quarter second and immediately shuts back off. You can trouble shoot this case with a second monitor substituted in.

A similar problem can happen with the computer case power supply. Trouble shooting can be done with a replacement power supply.

Comment: Don't think it's the monitor. When using it with my laptop I have no problems. Maybe it's related to the CPU heat sink as you say. Could it be that it needs new thermal paste?